# cassandra row fetch gives junk characters

Tags: java, cassandra, bigdata

Am learning Cassandra and have written a restclient which would read a file from the DB.

Below is my code to retrieve the data from the DB.

```
        ResultSet rs = getFile(fileName);
        Row row=rs.one();

        ByteBuffer filecontent =row.getBytes("file_content");
        byte[] data = new byte[filecontent.remaining()];
        ByteBuffer bb = filecontent.get(data);

        String filelocation = row.getString("file_location");
        String filename = row.getString("filename");

        ByteArrayInputStream filecontentfromDB= new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array());
        File file=writeToFile(filecontentfromDB,fileName);

        if (rs == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return file;
```

when I look at the returned file, I find some junk characters at the beginning and followed by my file contents.

Please help me in removing the junk data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yipee, found a solution, below lines should be replaced

```
String filelocation = row.getString("file_location");
        String filename = row.getString("filename");

        ByteArrayInputStream filecontentfromDB= new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array());
```

**with**

```
String filelocation = row.getString("file_location");
        String filename = row.getString("filename");
String bb = new String(filecontent.array(), filecontent.arrayOffset() + filecontent.position(), filecontent.remaining());
        ByteArrayInputStream filecontentfromDB= new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.getBytes());
```

It works .